# Whether there is a particular order for commands and their options in flask, If yes then, what is it?

Tags: python, flask, terminal

Actually I am a beginner learning flask and I am facing an issue with a command.
`flask --app flaskapp.py run`
above works fine but if i am doing
`flask run --app flaskapp.py`
it is not working.

I have seen `flask run --port=5500` so here the option i.e. --port is after the commmand i.e. run

also i have seen in the flask --help and i got **Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]**

So, i am confused that whether there is any particular order in python commands or flask commands or terminal commands with their option and commands.
Please help me understand.

also one thing do i need to write flaskapp.py or just the name of file without extension i.e. flaskapp ?

Comment: your question is between two options "do i need to write flaskapp.py OR just the name of file without extension", and your title says "If yes then.."  How can "Yes" be the answer to a question asking between two options? If yes is the answer, how do you know which of the two options is the correct one?

Comment: sorry @Elerium115 but u need to read the full question. What you are not looking at, I have added "also one thing to write flaskapp.py...........?" and my primary question is that whether there is a particular order for the command of flask, if yes then what is it ?
Please look at the whole question.

Comment: So the expected answer to the question "What is the order of the option and command..." is Yes or No? But this question is a consequence of another question being affirmative "If yes then...."  So how can a consequence be the cause of its own cause?

Comment: this here it is question for u sir 
whether there is a particular order for the command and its options of flask, if yes then what is it ?

Comment: Yes, the command needs to precede the options. Does this answer at least the first question?

Comment: thanku and sorry for the misunderstanding caused by my ambiguous question.

Comment: Have you taken a look at an example and try to replicate it? https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/quickstart/  In the example they use `flask --app hello run` so I suppose you have already tried what is in the getting started of the documentation.

Comment: yes i have read it, but sometimes it becomes harder to follow the documentations.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the command `flask --help` to see the options and how to use it.

> Usage: flask [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...
>
> An application to load must be given with the '--app' option, 'FLASK_APP' environment variable, or with a 'wsgi.py' or 'app.py' file in the current directory.

`--app` is an OPTION for flask, while `run` is a COMMAND, so the `--app` option should always come before the `run` command. If its omitted then its loading from an env variable.

If you run `flask run --help` you'll get

> Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]

You'll see a list of OPTIONS for the `run` command. In this case `--port` is an OPTION for the `run` command, so it should always go after the `run` command.

---

You can write the name of the file that creates the flask app or the python package name. For example if you had a folder called `flaskapp` with an `__init_.py` that creates the flask app, then you could run it like `flask --app flaskapp run`.

```
.
|   README.md
|
+---flaskapp
|   |   __init__.py
|   |   auth.py
```

Comment: please explain this further that what is __init__.py file and how does it creates a flask app. Do u mean to say that the folder flaskapp has a python file in which my main code of flask app is written (i.e. my main file which is currently flaskapp.py) or __init__.py is having some python code instead which will create the flask file code ?

Comment: also what is this auth.py ?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't explain myself completely. The `__init__.py` allows [python to treat a directory as a package](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages). If you have a directory ` flaskapp` with an \_\_init\_\_.py in it, python will treat flaskapp as a package and so you can just use `--app flaskapp` instead of passing a python file. `auth.py` was just part of the example, usually a flask app structure will have different files for different routes and functions.